How do I add a webpage on my browser opened from a locally saved .html file as a domain to an allow list?
I'm trying to reproduce a bug with a website and have created a locally hosted .html file with an iframe embed of some 3rd party software that we are having a problem with.
For the software iframe to load, it's necessary to add the domain to an 'allow list' in the 3rd party software settings.
However, in the url bar the address for the test page is: file:///Users/tr/Desktop/Test%20Page.html
So there is no domain to copy paste to the allow list, and the iframe does not open. What domain should i add to the 3rd party allow list for my page to run?
I tried my IP address but this doesn't seem to work :/

the html file will list an url for the iframe. it will have a domain. use that one.

Thanks - I tried that and it didn't work. The domain name in the iframe is the same as the 3rd party software provider (www.soundslice.com). Do you have any other suggestions?

No, without being able to see or test things, its impossible to troubleshoot unless you have done it before.
